# How to use navigator from older version of React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to use navigator from older version of React native. As given here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.43/navigator

For that I found a module named: `React Native Legacy Custom Components`

https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-custom-components

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-legacy-components

But I could not understand how to use this in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to install the library:

```sh
npm i react-native-custom-components

# or using yarn

yarn add react-native-custom-components
```

Then you can import the `Navigator` component:

```js
import { Navigator } from "react-native-custom-components";
```

and use it according to the documentation you posted.